# POST request with webmethods

Tags: rest, middleware, esb, webmethods

i am using webmethods platform 10.1 and i developed a service that is supposed to receive data as Post request. 
when i try to run it on IDE it works fine, but when i publish it and try to access it through API Portal, it does not work. 
i am not sure how to map my JSON to my Document. Can anyone please guide me in this regard?

I have attached my Document screen shot as well as the json i am trying to Post. 
Can anyone explain how both are not related, because when i post the below JSON to my service, i do not get the values.

[image]

[image]

```
   {
        "EventCompanyId": "443",
        "PositionTitleEn": "New post",
        "PositionTitleAr": "New post",
        "ReportsTo": "Manager",
        "KnowledgeRequiredEn": "Basic knowlege",
        "KnowledgeRequiredAr": "Basic knowledge",
        "ExperienceRequired": "7 years",
        "Gender": "1",
        "EducationLevel": "4",
        "CreatedBy": "1",
        "UpdatedBy": "1",
        "StartSalary": "35000",
        "EndSalary": "35000",
        "Status": "0",
        "Certificate": "BS",
        "YearsOfExperience": "7",
        "Major": "5",
        "Age": "30",
        "JobType": "1",
        "TrainingCourse": "",
        "Weekdays": "",
        "WorkingHours": "",
        "Language": "1",
        "Shift": "",
        "JobLocations": [
            {
                "EmiratesId": 3,
                "NumberOfVacancies": 3,
                "EmiratesArea": "United Arab Emirates",
                "Latitude": ,
                "Longitude": ,
                "EmirateEn": null,
                "EmirateAr": null,
                "EmirateName": null
            },
            {
                "EmiratesId": 6,
                "NumberOfVacancies": 23,
                "EmiratesArea": " Dubai - United Arab Emirates",
                "Latitude": 25.20447520001559,
                "Longitude": 55.28122901916504,
                "EmirateEn": null,
                "EmirateAr": null,
                "EmirateName": null
            },
            {
                "EmiratesId": 1,
                "NumberOfVacancies": 5,
                "EmiratesArea": "Dubai - United Arab Emirates",
                "Latitude": ,
                "Longitude": ,
                "EmirateEn": null,
                "EmirateAr": null,
                "EmirateName": null
            },
            {
                "EmiratesId": 2,
                "NumberOfVacancies": 3,
                "EmiratesArea": "D72 - Dubai - United Arab Emirates",
                "Latitude": ,
                "Longitude": ,
                "EmirateEn": null,
                "EmirateAr": null,
                "EmirateName": null
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found a solution for it, the problem was i needed to remove Job Properties from under Job Document, they should not be inside any other property.